# python fastapi didn't work get_current user function after set jwt token in cookie

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, fastapi

hi my get_current_user function can't get user data after set jwt token in cookie. here is my get current user function

```
async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme),db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        #headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},  
    )
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        mobile_number: str = payload.get("sub")
        if mobile_number is None:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_data = schemas.TokenData(mobile_number=mobile_number)
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception
    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.mobile_number==mobile_number).first()
    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    return user
```

here is my login code:

```
@router.post("/login")
def user_login(response: Response,username :str = Form(),password :str = Form(),db: Session = Depends(get_db),TwoFactorCode:str = Form(None)):
    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.mobile_number==username).first()
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(400, detail='wrong phone number or password')
    if not verify_password(password, user.password):
        raise HTTPException(400, detail='wrong phone number or password')
    
    
    access_token = create_access_token(data={"sub": user.mobile_number})
    response.set_cookie(key="Bearer", value=access_token)
    return {"status":"success"}
    #return {"token": access_token } #working if I set this
```

before set my token in cookies I can access my user attribute using my get_current_user function like get_current_user.id, get_current_user.mobile_number but now I can't.

Comment: Which line is the issue where you can't access the user information? i.e. are you having trouble accessing the information returned from the JWT, or are you having trouble accessing the properties on the `user` object returned by SQLAlchemy? Or are you having trouble accessing these properties in a function that depends on `get_current_user` that you haven't included?

Comment: @MatsLindh I am getting cookie response from my server but when trying to access user details using get_current_user function getting  HTTPException from credentials_exception

Comment: Then start by finding out _which_ of the `raise` statements that trigger, so that you can further debug that section of the code. i.e. is it failing to get the JWT token, is it failing to get the subject or is it failing to retrieve the user from the database?

Answer (score 0):

I have to pass jwt token from my cookie in my get_current_user function.

```
async def get_current_user(request: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    cookie = request.cookies.get("bearer")  
    
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Could not validate credentials",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
            
        )
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(cookie, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        
        mobile_number: str = payload.get("sub")
        if mobile_number is None:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_data = schemas.TokenData(mobile_number=mobile_number)
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception
    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.mobile_number==token_data.mobile_number).first()

    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    
    return user
```